# planar 4 regular graph

Tags: planar-graphs

if a planar 4 regular graph is only made of 3 and 4 corners and let´s say it has "s" a defined number of 4 corners then how van i find the number of 3 corners using the euler.P.formula . I saw online that it is the same number of 4 corners but with no proof. can anyone help ?

Comment: Well, to use the Euler formula for planar graphs, you must know what is it. And what is it, really?